# Change the icon image file dynamically when the user clicked the Map Pin: Google map

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps, ionic-framework

I need to change the icon image file dynamically when the user clicked the Map Pin.

I use the [Angular Google map component](https://github.com/angular/components/tree/master/src/google-maps) here.

I set the initial icon like so: (`Note:` I have removed all unwanted code here)

```
    const url = `assets/images/pngs/mapPins/${mapPinInformation?.category}_grey.png`;

    markerOptions = {
      icon: { url },
    } as google.maps.MarkerOptions;
  });
```

The above section is working fine. i.e. initial Icon image

When the user clicked the Map pin I use an Info window like so: (`Note:` no issues with Info window and it is working fine.)

```
@ViewChild(MapInfoWindow) infoWindow: MapInfoWindow;

openInfoCard(marker: MapMarker, mapPinInformation: MapPinInformationModel): void {
    this.infoWindow.open(marker);

      marker.icon = { // I have tried to changed it here. But it is not working?
      url: `assets/images/pngs/mapPins/${mapPinInformation?.category}_blue.png`,
         }; 
   
    }
```

This is how I call the open info window:

```
<google-map [options]="location?.googleMap?.mapOptions" height="100%" width="100%">
  <map-marker
    #marker="mapMarker"
    *ngFor="let mapPinAddressMarkerPosition of location?.googleMap?.mapPinAddressMarkerPositions"
    [position]="mapPinAddressMarkerPosition?.markerPosition"
    [options]="location?.googleMap?.markerOptions"
    (mapClick)="openInfoCard(marker, mapPinAddressMarkerPosition?.mapPinInformation)"
  >
  </map-marker>

  <map-info-window [position]="position">
   
    <app-location-details
        [mapPinInformation]="mapPinInformation"
    >
    </app-location-details>
  </map-info-window>
</google-map>
```

Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How awesome Typescript and VS code IntelliSense are. Just tried with few `dots` and it works now.

```
openInfoCard(marker: MapMarker, mapPinInformation: MapPinInformationModel): void {
   
    marker.marker.setIcon({
      url: `assets/images/pngs/mapPins/${mapPinInformation?.category}_blue.png`,
      
    });

    this.infoWindow.open(marker);
  }
```